# Агрегатные функции django

Tags: python, django

Есть агрегатная функция Count, которая выглядит следующим образом: `Count(<имя поля>[, distinct=False][, filter=None]`. Со слов в книге - *'Первым параметром указывается имя поля, имеющегося в записях, чье количество должно быть подсчитано.'*. Как появляется это поле в записях?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Это поле создается через написание классов моделей и дальнейшее применение миграций. Нет?

Comment: @mrEvgenX в книге про это ничего не говорится. Как понятнее объяснить я не знаю, разве что указать книгу со страницей)

Comment: Какая же это книга? Модели, вьюхи и шаблоны - краеугольные камни, с них все начинается и без этого никуда не уедешь. Напротив, можно написать кучу новичковых проектов для тренировки не используя агрегатные функции вообще.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Django 2.1 Практика создания веб сайтов на Python.

Comment: Я уже встречал другого автора вопроса, который по этой же книге что-то спрашивал. (мое субьективное мнение подкрепленное годами опыта) Ради всего святого выбросите эту книгу и почитайте документацию. Ведь эта книга в извращенном виде ее пересказывает.

Comment: Забудьте про агрегатные функции, попишите какой-нибудь учебный проект с нуля. На уютубе полно скринкастов. А книгу больше не открывайте, на полном серьезе, без шуток. У меня крайне эмоциональная реакция сие творение, но по-другому не могу - это халтура.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, я все таки подумаю об этом, спасибо)

Comment: С книгой там всё в порядке, по содержанию могу сказать что там есть описание создания моделей и миграций, а уже потом разговор идёт о выборке данных. Так что смотрите внимательнее